# not able to check if a square is empty tictactoe game jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tic-tac-toe

I'm coding a tictactoe game but the code which I'm using to check whether the user is clicking on an empty square or already filled is not working for me please see what mistake I am doing

```
function startgame(){
    var $board=$('#board');
    $('div.square').remove();

    for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
    $board.append($('<div/>').addClass('square').addClass('empty'));
    $('div.square.empty').click(function(){
        $this=$(this);

        if($('div.square.empty').length==0){

            displayendmsg();
        }
        else {
            $this.removeClass('empty');

            if(currentplayer=="X")
                $this.append($('<div><img src="cross.jpg">       </div>').addClass('cross').css('visibility','visible'));
            else
                $this.append($('<div><img src="circle.jpg">  </div>').addClass('circle').css('visibility','visible'));

            flipturn();
        }


    });
};
```

Even on clicking already occupied square I'm enterin the handler don know why ?

Answer (score 1):

I put together a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/7PSwc/) to get this thing alive. You capture the event only for empty elements (selector: div.square.empty), like this you would only find empty ones, you can't do a test for .empty length inside because this function only reacts on empty elements. Anyway I modified your function like this:

```
function startgame(){
    var $board=$('#board');
    $('div.square').remove();
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        $board.append($('<div/>').addClass('square empty'));
    }
    $board.on('click','.square',function() {
        var elm = $(this);
        if(elm.hasClass('empty')) {
            elm.removeClass('empty');
            if(player === 'x') {
               elm.addClass('x');
               player = 'c';
            } else {
               elm.addClass('c'); 
               player = 'x';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't remove the `empty` class. In your fiddle player `c` is always able to click all squares even the ones already clicked. Add `elm.removeClass('empty');` as last line within your `if(elm.hasClass('empty')) {` to ensure squares are `locked` after they have been clicked. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/7PSwc/1/

Comment: yeah I agree with the div.empty.length thing , but what's wrong with this "$('div.square.empty').click(function()"  thanks

Comment: @axel.michel: +1 for a working fiddle. Very nice, looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can check if that field has text or not.

```
if($.trim($("handler").text()) == '') //Then it is obviously empty.
```