# Not able to check if Tic-tac-toe a square is empty using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding a Tic-tac-toe game but the code which I'm using to check whether the user is clicking on an empty square or an already filled one is not working for me. Please find my mistake.

```
function startgame(){
    var $board=$('#board');
    $('div.square').remove();

    for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
        $board.append($('<div/>').addClass('square').addClass('empty'));

    $('div.square.empty').click(function(){
        $this=$(this);

        if($('div.square.empty').length==0){

            displayendmsg();
        }
        else {
            $this.removeClass('empty');

            if(currentplayer=="X")
                $this.append($('<div><img src="cross.jpg">        </div>').addClass('cross').css('visibility','visible'));
            else
                $this.append($('<div><img src="circle.jpg">  </div>').addClass('circle').css('visibility','visible'));

            flipturn();
        }


    });
};
```

Even when clicking on an already occupied square I enter the handler, and I don't know why.

Comment: Fyi, you should really use `var $this = $(this);` - without the `var` keyword you create a global which is almost always not what you want and sometimes (usually when it happens for loop variables) a great way to introduce hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Since this is probably a learning project I'll recommend that you try to do this without changing classes or having jQuery make any "decisions" for you. Ideally you have a game engine that is separate from the visual representation and interface, all you tell the game engine is that a certain tile has been clicked, and then it should itself decide if that is a legal action. It may not seem like a big advantage now, but for something more complicated you'll end up with an unmaintainable kludge coding the way you do now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [not able to check if a square is empty tictactoe game jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001366/not-able-to-check-if-a-square-is-empty-tictactoe-game-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) attaches an event handler on call time to all elements that match the selector. Even if the elements don't match the selector later on, the event handler will still be there.

Instead, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to check if the selector still applies for your event handler at the moment it is triggered:

```
$(document).on("click", "div.square.empty", function(){ alert("Clicked an empty square!"); });
```

Comment: Please.. [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)! `.on('click', func)` in the way you use it does *exactly the same* as `.click(func)` or `.bind('click', func)`

Comment: Oops, excusez-moi. Used `.live()` first, but then I saw it was deprecated, hence I updated to `.on()` but got the syntax not quite right. Fixed it now per the docs. Thanks.

Comment: No need for a document-wide delegate. The handler is bound after the squares are created so `$('div.square').on('click', '.empty', ...);` does the job.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Feel free to edit (or suggest an edit) to improve an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you bind the event handler only for the elements that match the selector at the time where you call the `.click(..)` function. However, you want to bind it on all elements but only trigger the function if the element has the correct class.

You can do this by using a *delegate*. In recent jQuery versions you do this using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$('div.square').on('click', '.empty', function() {
    // your code here
});
```